# Is there any where to get free testnet Bitcoins?

Tags: testnet, faucets

I'm building a project with bitcoins and want to test it with testnet. However, I don't have any testnet bitcoins, and despite the difficulty being less than 100 usually, I still haven't been able to mine a block on my PC (CPU only) after a day. Is there anywhere I could get just some small amount of testnet bitcoins for testing?

Comment: You can also use `regression testing` mode and generate as many coins as you wish on the go.

Comment: Also see: [How can I get more than 1 BTC on testnet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98887/5406)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(Link to faucet URL removed... please see the [community wiki answer further down the page](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/119937/516) for links of faucets.)

The term "faucet" has been used for quite some time for a site giving away small quantities of coins for free. If all links in this page stop working, a web search for "bitcoin testnet faucet" may find a different site.

Comment: The important part of this answer is the term "faucet"; even if a specific source ceases working, a web search as suggested should be able to find another source of testnet coins.

Answer (score 8):

One more site to get free test bitcoins...

http://kuttler.eu/bitcoin/btc/faucet/

Comment: manual sending there, so it might take some days - manu's is instant, see answer of Pavel

Answer (score 5):

http://bitcoinfaucet.uo1.net/ - about 4000 testnet coins now

Comment: keeps saying I'm bot, but I'm not. My wife had me tested!

Comment: it's trying to detect adblockers and fails badly by overblocking non-blockers :D

Comment: Worked for me, Instantly! (as of 15 Nov 2018; i know mentioning the date is redundant :)

Answer (score 4):

**Website Shutdown**

This worked for me today, they give 1BTC per request, theres captcha

https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet

Comment: It does not work now

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: Website Shutdown**

http://faucet.xeno-genesis.com/

working as of 2014-04-06 with about 2000+ testnet coins.

Comment: I got the error: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Answer (score 3):

Testnet3 bitcoins in http://faucet.luis.im

Active as of December 2015.

Answer (score 3):

https://blocktrail.com has a testnet faucet but requires login

Comment: http://www.bitcointestnetfaucet.com/ Free unlmited withdrawals at 0.05 BTC max.

Answer (score 2):

BTC Testnet faucet:

https://coinfaucet.eu/en/btc-testnet

<s>Working as of Oct 5, 2018</s>
**Defunct** as of 2023-10-06

Answer (score 2):

Just launched Bitcoin testnet faucet for developers!
https://tbtc.bitaps.com

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*This is a useful frequent topic, but answers outdate quickly. I’m starting this community wiki to collect all current answers in one place and to make it easier to amend and extend the list of testnet faucets. Please record the date when you update a line.*</sup>

| Faucet | Status | Last checked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [kuttler.eu](http://kuttler.eu/bitcoin/btc/faucet/) | **Works** | 2023-10-06 |
| [uo1.net](http://bitcoinfaucet.uo1.net/) | **Works** | 2023-10-06 |
| [bitaps.com](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/) | **Works** | 2023-10-06 |
| [coinfaucet.eu](https://coinfaucet.eu/en/btc-testnet) | Stuck on Cloudflare | 2023-10-06 |
| [onchain.io](https://onchain.io/bitcoin-testnet-faucet) | No response | 2023-10-06 |
| [manu.backend](https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet) | No response | 2023-10-06 |
| [luis.im](http://faucet.luis.im) | Abandoned domain | 2023-10-06 |
| [blocktrail.com](https://blocktrail.com/) | Business shut down | 2023-10-06 |
| [xeno-genesis.com](http://faucet.xeno-genesis.com/) | Abandoned domain | 2023-10-06 |

Answer (score 1):

Testnet3 faucet as louis is down: https://testnet.coinfaucet.eu/en/

Edit: **Defunct** as of 2023-10-06