# Where can I collect Bitcoins?

Tags: faucets

I haven't used Bitcoin for a long time, but I am interested in Bitcoin again. Where can I get free Bitcoins?

Comment: @UTF-8 Please [be nice](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Asker, are you looking for free Bitcoins, or a way to buy Bitcoins?

Comment: collecting free btcs

Comment: h2kyaw: Hey, welcome back. Unfortunately, free bitcoins are a thing of the past. There are still some clickworker offers that give you bitcoins, but in general they are not worth your time. Today, you might want to consider getting paid in Bitcoin, or buying them. You may want to check out [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406).

Comment: for testing some things you can use the testnet: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17690/21373

Answer (score 0):

Alas, there is no free lunch.

Try out http://www.coinbase.com for a convenient way to buy and store BTC securely.  It is US-based and self-assured against loss.